# Unable to connect to remote server from Hawtio dashboard

Tags: java, apache-camel, hawtio

I have a camel web application running on remote-server-1 which is a tomcat 8 server. I have attached a jolokia jvm agent on this tomcat as follows-

```
java -jar jolokia-jvm-1.3.5-agent.jar start <PID>
```

I get the following response on my local machine by accessing `http://remote-server-1:port/jolokia`-

```
{
    "request": {
        "type": "version"
    },
    "value": {
        "agent": "1.3.5",
        "protocol": "7.2",
        "config": {
            "maxDepth": "15",
            "discoveryEnabled": "true",
            "maxCollectionSize": "0",
            "agentId": "***.***.***.**-16224-35a7a114-jvm",
            "debug": "false",
            "agentType": "jvm",
            "historyMaxEntries": "10",
            "agentContext": "\/jolokia",
            "maxObjects": "0",
            "debugMaxEntries": "100"
        },
        "info": {
            "product": "tomcat",
            "vendor": "Apache",
            "version": "8.0.35"
        }
    },
    "timestamp": 1491307702,
    "status": 200
}
```

I also have hawtio.war deployed on my local-tomcat8.5. When I try to connect to this remote agent, I am redirected to login page. I am not able to figure out where am I going wrong. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Which hawtio version are you using?

Comment: I'm using hawtio version 1.5.0

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**From 2.10.1 on:** Use `hawtio.proxyAllowlist` instead of `hawtio.proxyWhitelist`. (Thanks rastadrian for pointing it out.)

---

Since hawtio 1.5.0 you need to add remote hosts to the `hawtio.proxyWhitelist` system property.

http://hawt.io/docs/configuration/#configuration-properties

> `hawtio.proxyWhitelist` - Comma-separated whitelist for target hosts that the hawtio-jmx Connect plugin can connect to via `ProxyServlet` (default `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`). All hosts that are not listed in this whitelist are denied to connect for security reasons. This option can be set to `*` to restore old behavior and whitelist all hosts. Prefixing an element of the list with `"r:"` allows to define a regexp (example: `localhost,r:myservers[0-9]+.mydomain.com`)

If you are using `hawtio.war` then modify its `WEB-INF/web.xml` like this:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jolokia-proxy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>io.hawt.web.ProxyServlet</servlet-class>
    <!--
      Comma-separated list of allowed target hosts. It is required for security.
      '*' allows all hosts but keep in mind it's vulnerable to security attacks.
    -->
    <init-param>
      <param-name>proxyWhitelist</param-name>
      <param-value>
        localhost,
        127.0.0.1,
        remote-server-1
      </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
```

Comment: it is worth noting that after version 2.10.1, this attribute has been renamed to `hawtio.proxyAllowlist`.

Comment: Doesn't work in Version 2.16.1. When I try to add a connection, I get "Host not whitelisted". I added -Dhawtio.proxyAllowList=SERVERNAME as well to the command line, same failure (launched with javaw, BTW, not with java, which bombs immediately)

Comment: @arayq2 Can you try not `hawtio.proxyAllowList` but `hawtio.proxyAllowlist`?

Comment: @Tadayoshi yes, that works, thanks. I'm still not happy with the interface.  (1) Can't edit the allow list from within the application (ok, maybe that shouldn't be possible), only the command line. (2) No way to exit the application cleanly. Having launched from the command line, I can only kill the browser (window, running the client), which leaves java running. Oh well, can't have everything...

Answer (score 16):

If you are using the runnable JAR version of Hawtio you can pass the parameter hawtio.proxyWhitelist also when starting the application:

```
java -Dhawtio.proxyWhitelist=SERVERNAME -jar hawtio-app-1.5.3.jar
```

Comment: Doesn't work.  When I try to add a connection, I get "Host not whitelisted".  I added -Dhawtio.proxyAllowList=SERVERNAME as well to the command line (launched with javaw, not java), same failure.  (Version 2.16.1)

Comment: Could it be that it is just a typo with the uppercase letter "L" ? The documentation states that since version 2.10.1 the correct parameter is hawtio.proxyAllowlist. So it should be 'java -Dhawtio.proxyAllowlist=SERVERNAME -jar hawtio-app-2.16.1.jar' in your case